# Limit as x goes to infinity of (50)(cosx)^3/(x^2+10)

Tags: limits

How do I find the limit  $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{50(\cos x)^3}{x^2+10}?$$

I have tried dividing by $1/x$, so it becomes ($50(\cos x)^3)/(x)/(x +\frac{10}x)$. But I seem to be stuck from here. Am I even on the right track?

Comment: Find the limit of the absolute value. Note $|(\cos x)^3|\le 1$.

Comment: so do i do the squeeze theorem?

Comment: You multiplied the numerator by $x$ but divided the denominator by $x$.

Comment: @DavidMitra oh thank you! i did the squeeze theorem and i got 0 for both sides, so that is why the limit is 0! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $-1\leqslant\cos x\leqslant 1$, we have $-1\leqslant\cos^3x\leqslant1$, hence $-50\leqslant50\cos^3x\leqslant50$. And since $\tfrac{1}{x^2+10}$ is always positive, we can deduce that :

$$
-\frac{50}{x^2+10}\leqslant\frac{50\cos^3x}{x^2+10}\leqslant\frac{50}{x^2+10}.
$$

And by the squeeze theorem :

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{50\cos^3x}{x^2+10}=0.
$$